# Extract data from array - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using the unleashed_py library to extract Unleashed data.

The sample of the output is as below where there could be several items in the invoice:

```
[{
 'OrderNumber': 'SO-00000742',
  'QuoteNumber': None,
  'InvoiceDate': '/Date(1658496322067)/',
  'InvoiceLines': [{'LineNumber': 1,
    'LineType': None},
   {'LineNumber': 2,
    'LineType': None}],
  'Guid': '8f6b89da-1e6e-42288a24-902a-038041e04f06',
  'LastModifiedOn': '/Date(1658496322221)/'}]
```

I need to get a df:

[image]

If I run the below script, the invoice lines just get appended with the common fields such as ordernumber, quotenumber, invoicedate, guide, and lastmodifiedon not getting repeated.

```
order_number = []
quote_number = []
invoice_date = []
invoicelines = []
invoice_line_number = []
invoice_line_type = []
guid = []
last_modified = []


for item in df:
    order_number.append(item.get('OrderNumber'))
    quote_number.append(item.get('QuoteNumber'))
    invoice_date.append(item.get('InvoiceDate'))
    guid.append(item.get('Guid'))
    last_modified.append(item.get('LastModifiedOn'))
    lines = item.get('InvoiceLines')
    for item_sub_2 in lines:
        invoice_line_number.append('LineNumber')
        invoice_line_type.append('LineType')

df_order_number = pd.DataFrame(order_number)
df_quote_number = pd.DataFrame(quote_number)
df_invoice_date = pd.DataFrame(invoice_date)
df_invoice_line_number  = pd.DataFrame(invoice_line_number)
df_invoice_line_type = pd.DataFrame(invoice_line_type)
df_guid = pd.DataFrame(guid)
df_last_modified = pd.DataFrame(last_modified)

df_row = pd.concat([
df_order_number,
df_quote_number,
df_invoice_date,
df_invoice_line_number,
df_invoice_line_type,
df_guid,
df_last_modified
], axis = 1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate, just create the dataframe out of the list of dictionaries you have, then explode `InvoiceLines` columns then apply `pd.Series` and join it with the original dataframe:

```py
data = [{
    'OrderNumber': 'SO-00000742',
    'QuoteNumber': None,
    'InvoiceDate': '/Date(1658496322067)/',
    'InvoiceLines': [{'LineNumber': 1,
                      'LineType': None},
                     {'LineNumber': 2,
                      'LineType': None}],
    'Guid': '8f6b89da-1e6e-42288a24-902a-038041e04f06',
    'LastModifiedOn': '/Date(1658496322221)/'}]


df=pd.DataFrame(data).explode('InvoiceLines')
out=pd.concat([df['InvoiceLines'].apply(pd.Series),
           df.drop(columns=['InvoiceLines'])],
          axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
#out

   LineNumber  LineType  OrderNumber QuoteNumber            InvoiceDate  \
0         1.0       NaN  SO-00000742        None  /Date(1658496322067)/   
0         2.0       NaN  SO-00000742        None  /Date(1658496322067)/   
                                       Guid         LastModifiedOn  
0  8f6b89da-1e6e-42288a24-902a-038041e04f06  /Date(1658496322221)/  
0  8f6b89da-1e6e-42288a24-902a-038041e04f06  /Date(1658496322221)/
```

I'm leaving the date conversion and column renames for you cause I believe you can do that yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it worked! I am looking at your two lines and my > 32 rows and feel ashamed.

Comment: @eponkratova it happens initially when you are new to pandas, I also feel kinda the same when I look back to my answers in stackoverflow when I'd just started.