# How to convert a Json with multidimensional array into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, multidimensional-array

Hy guys, i'm having a problem to convert this json into a dataframe.

I have requested this json using an API:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

acordo_leniencia = requests.get(url_acordo_leniencia,headers=chave)
json = acordo_leniencia.json()
```

My json has this structure:

```
[{'id': 800001,
  'dataInicioAcordo': '27/05/2019',
  'dataFimAcordo': '16/10/2019',
  'orgaoResponsavel': 'Prefeitura Municipal de Itaguaí - RJ',
  'situacaoAcordo': 'Em Execução',
  'sancoes': [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'AMBIENTAL ENGENHARIA E CONSULTORIA LTDA',
    'razaoSocial': 'AMBIENTAL ENGENHARIA E CONSULTORIA LTDA',
    'nomeFantasia': '',
    'cnpj': '22641641000168',
    'cnpjFormatado': '22.641.641/0001-68'}],
  'quantidade': 1},
 {'id': 1600001,
  'dataInicioAcordo': '15/10/2021',
  'dataFimAcordo': '15/04/2023',
  'orgaoResponsavel': 'Ministério da Transparência e Controladoria-Geral da União',
  'situacaoAcordo': 'Em Execução',
  'sancoes': [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'MACAUBAS ENERGETICA SA',
    'razaoSocial': 'MACAUBAS ENERGETICA SA',
    'nomeFantasia': '',
    'cnpj': '09194393000196',
    'cnpjFormatado': '09.194.393/0001-96'},
   {'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'SEABRA ENERGETICA S/A',
    'razaoSocial': 'SEABRA ENERGETICA S/A',
    'nomeFantasia': '',
    'cnpj': '09196341000159',
    'cnpjFormatado': '09.196.341/0001-59'},
   {'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'STATKRAFT ENERGIAS RENOVAVEIS S/A',
    'razaoSocial': 'STATKRAFT ENERGIAS RENOVAVEIS S/A',
    'nomeFantasia': '',
    'cnpj': '00622416000141',
    'cnpjFormatado': '00.622.416/0001-41'},
   {'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'NOVO HORIZONTE ENERGETICA S/A',
    'razaoSocial': 'NOVO HORIZONTE ENERGETICA S/A',
    'nomeFantasia': '',
    'cnpj': '09214349000109',
    'cnpjFormatado': '09.214.349/0001-09'}],
  'quantidade': 4},
```

I tried to convert into a dataframe:

```
parsed = acordo_leniencia.json()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(parsed)
```

but it didn't work as I was expecting

```
id  dataInicioAcordo    dataFimAcordo   orgaoResponsavel    situacaoAcordo  sancoes quantidade
0   800001  27/05/2019  16/10/2019  Prefeitura Municipal de Itaguaí - RJ    Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'AMBIENTAL ...   1
1   1600001 15/10/2021  15/04/2023  Ministério da Transparência e Controladoria-Ge...   Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'MACAUBAS E...   4
2   1600001 15/10/2021  15/04/2023  Ministério da Transparência e Controladoria-Ge...   Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'MACAUBAS E...   4
3   1600001 15/10/2021  15/04/2023  Ministério da Transparência e Controladoria-Ge...   Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'MACAUBAS E...   4
4   1600001 15/10/2021  15/04/2023  Ministério da Transparência e Controladoria-Ge...   Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'MACAUBAS E...   4
5   1100001 18/07/2020  18/07/2021  PREFEITURA MUNICIPAL DE CASIMIRO DE ABREU - RJ  Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'ANDRI SOLU...   1
6   1500001 28/01/2022  28/01/2025  Controladoria-Geral do Estado de Santa Catarin...   Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'NEOWAY TEC...   1
7   1300002 07/06/2021  30/06/2041  Ministério da Transparência e Controladoria-Ge...   Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'SICPA BRAS...   3
8   1300002 07/06/2021  30/06/2041  Ministério da Transparência e Controladoria-Ge...   Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'SICPA BRAS...   3
9   1300002 07/06/2021  30/06/2041  Ministério da Transparência e Controladoria-Ge...   Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'SICPA BRAS...   3
10  1000004 31/07/2019  31/01/2038  Ministério da Transparência e Controladoria-Ge...   Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'CONSTRUCOE...   3
11  1000004 31/07/2019  31/01/2038  Ministério da Transparência e Controladoria-Ge...   Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'CONSTRUCOE...   3
12  1000004 31/07/2019  31/01/2038  Ministério da Transparência e Controladoria-Ge...   Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'CONSTRUCOE...   3
13  1000007 10/07/2017  10/07/2038  Ministério da Transparência e Controladoria-Ge...   Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'U T C ENGE...   3
14  1000007 10/07/2017  10/07/2038  Ministério da Transparência e Controladoria-Ge...   Em Execução [{'nomeInformadoOrgaoResponsavel': 'U T C ENGE...   3
```

**As you can see, the column "sancoes" have informations that are still between the "[]". How can I get them off there as a dataframe???**

Regards,
Victor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract data from array - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73425151/extract-data-from-array-python) The linked question is same to yours, only the data attribute are different.

Comment: Bingo! That´s excalty what I need!! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The pandas dataframe construction is correct, because `sancoes` entries as lists themselves.

Unless you specify more clearly your desired output, it is difficult to help you.